# configurations factories.yml in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, mailer

At first i have emial `aaa@bbb.com` and there is another email doesn't belong to me for example `ccc@ddd.com` or anything else blabla@bla.com

`IN factories.yml` i configured the mailer with the following

```
mailer:
  class: sfMailer
  param:
    logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
    charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
    delivery_strategy: realtime
    transport:
      class: Swift_SmtpTransport
      param:
        host:       smtp.localhost.com
        port:       25
        username:   aaa@bbb.com
        password:   123456
```

In the code ... to send an email i use

```
         $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject('sub')->setFrom('ccc@ddd.com')->setTo('yahoo@yahoo.com');
         sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->send($message);
```

Now i setFrom() ---> `ccc@ddd.com` however i configured the `factories.yml` with another email `aaa@bbb.com`!!!!

Finally the sent mail is from `ccc@ddd.com` which isn't my email actually

Comment: Thanks god I don't need this framework...

Comment: @MichelFeldheim what does that mean ? its a very simple framework to use - the documentation is second to none .. whats your issue with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `factories.yml` file details the SMTP details

```
param:
    host:       smtp.localhost.com
    port:       25
    username:   aaa@bbb.com
    password:   123456
```

Here the `username` is the username used for logging onto the smtp server. Not the email address the email will be sent from.

This line

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                  ->setSubject('sub')
                  ->setFrom('ccc@ddd.com')
```

determines the from address of the email.

[See the docs for swift mailer for the methods](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#the-structure-of-a-message)

Comment: that is mean i can send email from any other mail even i don't own it ?!!

Comment: @user1272589 you can **try** but most recipients reject mail where the sending relay domain is different from the from envelope domain - this is SPAM

Comment: yaah ... you mean that when the Sender not the same as From ... it considered as spamming

Answer (score 0):

the factories parameters are only used for the smtp autentication.
in my experience, most of the clients don't accept mails launched from sites different that the one defined in the email.

for example,

```
param:
    host:       smtp.example.com
    port:       25
    username:   mail@example.com
    password:   123
```

could send with no problem mails from anything@example.com, but couldn't send them from anything@otherdomain.com. It will be rejected in most cases.

the same goes when the host is localhost, it will only work fine if you use the domain that is hosting your application.

```
param:
        host:       localhost
        port:       25
        username:   mail@localorassociatedmail.com
        password:   123
```

if hosted on aaa.com, it will only work fine with the From: set to anything@aaa.com.

I'm not suer if it's considered spam, in some cases it doesn't even go out.